# Path Connectedness argument for $SO(n, \mathbb{R})$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am trying to prove path connectedness of $SO(n, \mathbb{R})$. I have seen several different proofs for the same. But I had a thought and wanted to know whether it would help in any way. I took two arbitrary matrices in $SO(2)$ first, one expressed by $\theta$ and another by $\phi$ of the form:

$$ \left[ \begin{array}{lr}
\cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\
-\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{array} \right]
$$

I then used the curve $ \sigma : [0,1] \to SO(2)$ given by
$$ \sigma(t) = \left[ \begin{array}{lr}
\cos(t\theta + (1-t)\phi) & \sin(t\theta + (1-t)\phi) \\
-\sin(t\theta + (1-t)\phi) & \cos(t\theta + (1-t)\phi)
\end{array} \right]
$$

Is this alright? Can the above argument be extended to $SO(3)$ or $SO(n)$ in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is alright, essentially you use that $SO(2)$ is homeomorphoic to $S^1$. A *similar* method is possible for $SO(n)$, but the parametrization is a bit more involved. An inductive proof by continuously transforming one column to the standard base vector (using precisely this $n=2$ case) works best, I suggest.

Comment: Thanks. But I was unable to get your last statement. What do you mean by continuously transforming one column to the standard base vector?

Comment: I got what you said. Sorry for the silly comment.